# Eureka forms gives error EXC_BAD_INSTRUCTION INVOP

Tags: eureka-forms

I have just started using Eureka Forms in my Swift 3 project.
I have created my first form with a TextRow that looks like this:

```
<<< TextRow() {
    $0.tag = tagname
    $0.title = title
    $0.placeholder = placeholder
}
```

It displays correctly on the simulator, however when I click in the field I immediately get a crash:

```
EXC_BAD_INSTRUCTION (code =EXC_1386,INVOP,subcode=0x0)
```

On the guard line (from the Eureka framework):

```
private func displayValue(useFormatter: Bool) -> String? {
   guard let v = row.value else { return nil }
```

It must be something simple, can anybody point me in the right direction please?

Comment: Are you using the latest (3.0.0) version? Maybe it's an older one. In the latest, the TextRow class init expects a String argument.

Comment: Installed using Carthage: github "xmartlabs/Eureka" ~> 3.0
My understanding is that you can either pass the 'title' as a String argument parameter, or you can set it as I have above.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That error seems to say that the `row.value` is needed, so maybe you can add an initial value ("") in the init callback. It may be an old or unreleased commit. Please try the latest version or see if the version you used has that particular bug.

Comment: Yes, I agree.  The row.value is clearly missing.  I tried adding $0.value = "" in the above code segment, but it made no difference to the error.

Comment: I am running the same row object without problems. Please add information on the `section` you are using and how you are creating the `FormViewController`

Comment: It can also help if you add the stack trace up to the exception, since that function is called by the TextViewDelegate function defined in the `_TextAreaCell`, so if it gets there without a row, something strange was setup.

Comment: Thanks for your help Efren, your suggestions got me thinking about the creation of the FormViewController.